# Python code not executing main function and subsequent function calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

In this simple python code, my main function is not being executed.

```py
import os
import sys


def getTechWork(techName):
    print("Finding technicians")


if __name__ == " __main__ ":
    print("Main Function")
    getTechWork("Adams, Keith")
```

The console shows no output from the print statements. If I put in a module level print statement outside of the functions, it is executed properly when I run the code. I'm running PyCharm Community 2019.2.1 and using Python 3.7 as my interpreter.

Comment: you have extra spaces in '__main__' string

Comment: Handy tip: if your `if` statement is not doing what you want it to do, include a `print` statement directly before the `if` statement. If that prints ok, but your `if` branch does not execute, then your `if` statement is not doing what you think it's doing. Read it again carefully. Print out the variables in the `if` statement.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Answer (score 3):

you have extra spaces in the string `" __main__ "`

```
import os
import sys


def getTechWork(techName):
    print("Finding technicians")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Main Function")
    getTechWork("Adams, Keith")
```

Comment: good spot, still a typo though and so not a great SO question (should be closed)

Comment: its okay, we all miss small mistakes now and then.

Answer (score 2):

I am far from being an expert in python but I think you should replace :

```
if __name__ == " __main__ ":
```

By:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

The spaces in the if statements are, I think, the cause

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in statement
`if __name__==" __main__ ":`
`" __main__ "` is having extra spaces. Which means string has been changed.
You can check this by writing `print("__main__"==" __main__ ")` this will return `False`

Answer (score -2):

define a main function and invoke it in if block like:

```
import os
import sys


def getTechWork( techName ):
    print("Finding technicians")

def main():
    print("Main Function")
    getTechWork("Adams, Keith")

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful. You skipped over mentioning the actual problem (the typos in `" __main__ "`) and suggest to define a specific main function, which may be useful for code clarity, but is not in any way necessary to resolve the problem in the question.